# How to let elements disappear while scrolling, with hidden but functional scrollbar?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a page where the user can scroll down. The scroll bar is hidden but functional (pushed to the side with inner&outer divs and "right: -17px;").

In this forum I saw some scroll-disappear solutions, but only in jQuery, but I want to learn pure/vanilla JavaScript before I use any library.

I tried to write my own simple JS code. It worked for the first when I haven't hide the scrollbar, seems I have to change something in the JS code.

Here is my code: (I also created a snippet below to simulate):

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEffectOne);
      function scrollEffectOne()
      {
        var hidethis = document.getElementById("box");

        hidethis.style.opacity = "0.1";
      }
```

```css
*
    {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      font-family: Arial;
    }
    #outer
    {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
      position: absolute;
    }
    #inner
    {
      top: 0px;
      right: -17px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      position: absolute;
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #frame_1
    {
      top: 0px;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #22E1FF 0%, #1D8FE1 48%, #625EB1 100%);
    }
    #frame_2
    {
      top: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #D4FFEC 0%, #57F2CC 48%, #4596FB 100%);
    }
    #frame_3
    {
      top: 200%;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      position: absolute;
      background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #473B7B 0%, #3584A7 51%, #30D2BE 100%);
    }
    #box
    {
      width: 350px;
      height: 100px;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
      border-radius: 10px;
      opacity: 1;
    }
    #box a
    {
      opacity: 1;
      font-size: 15px;
      color: white;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      position: absolute;
    }
    #box b
    {
      color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>TEST</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      </head>

      <body>

        <div id="outer">
          <div id="inner">

            <div id="frame_1">
              <div id="box">
                <a>Hide Me <b>while scrolling</b> !</a>
              </div>

            </div>

            <div id="frame_2"></div>

            <div id="frame_3"></div>

          </div>
        </div>

      </body>

    </html>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="outer">
      <div id="inner">

        <div id="frame_1">
          <div id="box">
            <a>Hide Me <b>while scrolling</b> !</a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <div id="frame_2"></div>

        <div id="frame_3"></div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </body>


<style>
*
{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: Arial;
}
#outer
{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}
#inner
{
  top: 0px;
  right: -17px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#frame_1
{
  top: 0px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #22E1FF 0%, #1D8FE1 48%, #625EB1 100%);
}
#frame_2
{
  top: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #D4FFEC 0%, #57F2CC 48%, #4596FB 100%);
}
#frame_3
{
  top: 200%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-225deg, #473B7B 0%, #3584A7 51%, #30D2BE 100%);
}
#box
{
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}
#box a
{
  opacity: 1;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  position: absolute;
}
#box b
{
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.3);
}

</style>

<script>
  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEffectOne);
  function scrollEffectOne()
  {
    var hidethis = document.getElementById("box");

    hidethis.style.opacity = "0.1";
  }
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: opacity is not a string, it is a number.

Comment: what do you mean by that? do i have to change "0.1" to 0.1?

Comment: @epascarello This is incorrect, the value is converted to a string either way. `'0.1'` or `0.1`, either way get turned into `'0.1'` on assignment.

Comment: I replaced it but unfortunately it still doesn't work...

Comment: Your code looks right but it didnt work until i changed the useCapture option to true. To be honest, I dont know why it has do be true. `window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEffectOne, true);` Read more that about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: @ArayniMax, you are right, adding "true" fixed it! thank you, write it as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks right but it didnt work until i changed the useCapture option to true. To be honest, I dont know why it has do be true.

`window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollEffectOne, true);`

Read more that about here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Comment: Thank you very much! Would it work for every browser or only for firefox?